# ActiveRecord: Sum the count of relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have models like this:

```
class Manufacturer
  has_many :models
end

class Model
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  has_many :widgets
end

class Widget
  belongs_to :model
end
```

How can I define a `widget_count` method on `Manufacturer`? That is, the sum of all the widgets for all the models that belong to that manufacturer.

For example, if I have a Manufacturer with 3 models, and each of those models has 3 widgets, then I'd like a `#widget_count` method on `Manufacturer` that returns 9.

This would work, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it with ActiveRecord:

```
manufactuer.models.map { |m| m.widgets.count }.sum
```

Comment: I want to do something like `manufacturer.models.sum(:count)`, but count isn't a field. Is there a way to do this with ActiveRecord? I've edited my question, so hopefully it's a bit clearer.

Comment: Just add the association to `Manufacturer` e.g. `has_many :widgets, through: :models` then `manufacturer.widgets.count` will work. [Check This Out](http://ryandeussing.com/blog/2013/06/12/nested-associations-and-has-many-through/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding the answer that engineersmnky pointed to in the comments on the question, as this was exactly what I'm after.

Add this association to the `Manufacturer` model:

```
has_many :widgets, through: :models
```

There's more information in this article: ["Nested Associations and Has_many :through, :source"](http://ryandeussing.com/blog/2013/06/12/nested-associations-and-has-many-through/).

Answer (score 0):

Left join + group + count in ActiveRecord:

```
Manufacturer.
  joins('left join models on models.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id left join widgets on widgets.model_id = models.id').
  select('manufacturer.*, count(widgets.id) as widget_count').
  group('manufacturer.id')
```

`Manufacturer.find(1).widget_count #=> 3`